# How can I drive this laptop screen?

Tags: interface, video, plug, lvds, laptop

How can I drive this screen?

It's a 1920x1200 display from an old Dell Inspiron 6000 which is now dead, but the screen is great and I want to use it in a project. Is that a standard (either physical or electrical) plug, and does anything drive it? (either some kind of adapter from hdmi/dvi/vga, or directly from a newer laptop)

Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

[Full resolution image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/j3ArJD5ytoVhk_-9s3rc8DOzlgqWEyAYA23xFYDoSlw=w5472-h3648-no)

Comment: With great difficulty. You need to find (a) the spec of the screen (pinouts, signal levels, etc.), and (b) find an LCD controller (one specifically for LVDS panels) which has the correct firmware to suit your panel.

Comment: You can do it potentially with something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/251979911279) - I've used something similar for a laptop panel. (p.s. I am in no way endorsing the eBay item/seller, just using it as an example as it was the first result when searching "LCD panel to VGA" in eBay search).

Comment: AliExpress has a number of LVDS driver boards available similar to what Tom shows on ebay. Gargoyle aliexpress and various likely terms or search their site. YMMV. Do report back. It's something I'd like to know more about the practical successes of -old laptop screen abound and seem to make potentially more compact monitors than are usually available.

Answer (score 1):

[image: MT6820-B Universal LVDS LCD Monitor Driver Controller Board 5V 10"-42" New]

you can try with this Im making this proyect use old laptop to monitor